# How i can get bigquery table data in google script?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

> I want to bigquery table data using app script ,I am using this code but i am getting job id, i dont job id i want table data please help me this.

```
    function runQuery() {
     DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    var projectId = 'imran-338706';
   var request = {
   query: 'SELECT network_affiliate_name FROM `imran-338706.imranabc.bhk` LIMIT 10',
 useLegacySql: false
 }
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
   var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
console.log(queryResults)
}
```

Comment: @KrishanuSengupta okay but please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified using the following code for queries returning small amount of data  :

```
function runQuery() {
DriveApp.getRootFolder();
var projectId = ProjectID;
var request = {
 query: 'SELECT * from `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests` limit 2',
 useLegacySql: false
}
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
var rows = queryResults.rows;
 
var header = "";
for (var i = 0; i < queryResults.schema.fields.length; i++){
header+= " " + queryResults.schema.fields[i].name;
}
console.log(header)
 
 
var data = new Array(rows.length);
var string = ""
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
 var cols = rows[i].f;
 data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
 for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
   data[i][j]= cols[j].v;
   string+= " "+ data[i][j]
 
 }
 console.log(string);
 }
}
```

It gave the schema and row contents:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241253/discussion-on-answer-by-krishanu-sengupta-how-i-can-get-bigquery-table-data-in-g).